# Obtener una Imagen de un servidor con metodo GET

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview, http-get

Buenos días, me he encontrado con un problema al hacer mi app de android con android studio.

Lo que necesito es coger una imagen .png de un servidor (dada una url) mediante el método GET y mostrarla por pantalla.

He visto algún tutorial antiguo pero la sintaxis ahora es diferente y no funciona correctamente. Alguien me podría poner algún ejemplo de como seria el código ha usar o pasarme algún enlace actualizado.

Este es el codigo que estoy tratando de usar pero no me funciona :(

Soy novatillo en lo que aplicaciones android se refiere y necesitaria un cable. Gracias con antelación y un saludo

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"> 

 <ImageView android:id="@+id/image_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

.java

```
package com.jonsegador.examples.externalimage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Main extends Activity {
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Bitmap loadedImage;
    private String imageHttpAddress = "http://jonsegador.com/wp-content/apezz.png";            

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);       
        downloadFile(imageHttpAddress);
    }

    void downloadFile(String imageHttpAddress) {
        URL imageUrl = null;
        try {
            imageUrl = new URL(imageHttpAddress);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.connect();
            loadedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(conn.getInputStream());
            imageView.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error cargando la imagen: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

fuente : http://josehernandez.xyz/2011/01/18/servicio-web-php.html

Comment: No te funciona, pero que error se despliega en el LogCat o la consola, has realizado debugging?

Answer (score 2):

Recuerda que cuando necesites realizar una conexión a internet, necesitas agregara tu AndroidManifest.xml el permiso:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

En cuanto a la descarga no necesitas realizar una petición `GET` para poder descargar la imagen desde un url y mostrarla en un `ImageView`.

El problema que tienes en tu ejemplo, es algo obvio ya que es que estas tratando de realizar la descarga así como agregar la imagen en el `ImageView` en el hilo principal, lo puedes visualizar dentro del `LogCat`.

Para este tipo de operaciones te sugiero agregar un AsyncTask.

#### Como descargar imagen en un ImageView mediante AsynctTask.

Creas un Asynctask donde el proceso de descarga se realiza dentro del método `doInBackground()` :

```
class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public LoadImage(ImageView imageView) {
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            return downloadBitmap(params[0]);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("LoadImage class", "doInBackground() " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (isCancelled()) {
            bitmap = null;
        }

        if (imageViewReference != null) {
            ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                if (bitmap != null) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private Bitmap downloadBitmap(String url) {
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            URL uri = new URL(url);
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) uri.openConnection();
            int statusCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();
            if (statusCode != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                return null;
            }

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            if (inputStream != null) {
                Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                return bitmap;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
            Log.e("LoadImage class", "Descargando imagen desde url: " + url);
        } finally {
            if (urlConnection != null) {
                urlConnection.disconnect();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

y llamarías de esta forma el `AsyncTask` para cargar la imagen descargada, definiendo el contenedor `ImageView` y el url de la imagen a descargar:

```
   private ImageView imageView;
   private String imageURL = "http://jonsegador.com/wp-content/apezz.png";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        //downloadFile(imageURL);
        //AsyncTask recibe la referencia del ImageView y la url a descargar.
        new LoadImage(imageView).execute(imageURL);
    }
```

para obtener:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

te también aconsejo otras opciones que deberías revisar como son [**GLIDE**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) o **[PICASSO](http://square.github.io/picasso/)**, cuya implementación es muy sencilla.