# Mejor metodo para activity detalle

Tags: java, android

Tengo un recyclerview con 10 ítems y al hacer click se abre una activity detalle para cada uno de ellos. ¿Cuál es el mejor método para crear un Activity detalles para cada item? El xml del activity detalle es igual para todos solo cambia el contenido de los Textview y el contenido del imageview.¿Existe alguna manera de utilizar un solo activity detalle y que vaya cambiando el contenido según el ítem seleccionado? Ya que en este momento tengo creado 10 activity detalles.

"Disculpen creo que no me explique bien. Lo único que comparten los items del recyclerview y el activity detalle, es la imagen a través de un shared transition. Todo el contenido de los text view son diferentes. Lo que quise explicar es que los actyvities detalle para cada item comparten el mismo xml, y cambian la información dependiendo el ítem seleccionado. Por lo tanto capaz exista una manera, y seguro la hay, de crear solo un activity detalle que comparta la imagen y cambie los contenidos de sus text view dependiendo el ítem seleccionado. Desde ya muchas gracias por su paciencia."

dejo los xml del actyviti detalle (por ejemplo el de estática) y del ítem que se utiliza en el recyclerview, verán como lo único que se comparte es el imageview ya que comparten el transition name.

Soy novato.

Gracias

```
static class Item1Holder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    public final TextView nombre, text;
    public final ImageView imagen;
    public Item1Holder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        nombre= (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView90);
        imagen=(ImageView)itemView.findViewById(imageView2);
        text=(TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView91);

        itemView.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = null;
                switch (getAdapterPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        intent = new Intent(context, MruyMruv.class);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        intent = new Intent(context, TVerticalyCLibre.class);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        intent = new Intent(context, TOblicuo.class);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        intent = new Intent(context, MCUyMCUV.class);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        intent = new Intent(context, Dinamica.class);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        intent = new Intent(context, MGravitatorio.class);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        intent = new Intent(context, FElastica.class);
                        break;
                    case 7:
                        intent = new Intent(context, MOS.class);
                        break;
                    case 8:
                        intent = new Intent(context, Estatica.class);
                        break;
                    case 9:
                        intent = new Intent(context, PenduloSimple.class);
                        break;
                    case 10:
                        intent = new Intent(context, Hidroestatica.class);
                        break;
                }
                ActivityOptionsCompat option = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation((Activity) context, imagen, context.getString(R.string.image_transition));
                context.startActivity(intent, option.toBundle());
                ((Activity) context).getWindow().setExitTransition(TransitionInflater.from(context).inflateTransition(R.transition.shared_element_exit));
            }
        });
    }
```

actyviti estática xml

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card19"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/estaticamenor"
        android:transitionName="@string/image_transition" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    layout="@layout/toolbar"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteWidth="384dp"
    tools:layout_conversion_absoluteHeight="72dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="300dp">

</include>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/card20"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="12dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:text="@string/Estatica"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="160dp"/>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Item xml (row)

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="70dp"
    android:elevation="7dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView90"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:shadowColor="#212121"
        android:shadowDx="-8"
        android:shadowDy="1"
        android:shadowRadius="10"
        android:text="TextView2"
        android:textColor="#fafafa"
        android:textSize="48sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card1"
    android:layout_width="370dp"
    android:layout_height="440dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="2dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#455a64"
    app:cardCornerRadius="3dp"
    app:cardElevation="4dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card2"
    android:layout_width="315dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="#c9cd5c"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView91"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="TextView3"
        android:textColor="#eceff1"
        android:textSize="12.5sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:transitionGroup="false" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card3"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="280dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="315dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="0dp"
    app:cardElevation="6dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:transitionName="@string/image_transition" />

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/Image1"
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:elevation="7dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/comillas"
    android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"/>
```

Comment: Lo puedes hacer mediantes bundle como detalla @jorgesys

Answer (score 2):

Lo que realizas es correcto, usar `RecyclerView` y configurar un Listener para detectar el click en el elemento, pero si duda solo requieres una sola Activity en el caso que comentas.

> Si el activity detalle es igual para todos solo cambia el contenido de
>   los Textview y el contenido del imageview.

Crea una Activity con un Layout que tenga esos elementos y simplemente envia los datos mediante un bundle.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, ActivityDetalle.class);
    intent.putExtra("Titulo", titulo);
    intent.putExtra("Descripción", descripcion);
    intent.putExtra("Imagen", urlImagen);
    startActivity(intent);
```

En la Activity destino puedes tomar los valores y agregarlos a su respectiva vista:

```
Bundle valores = this.getIntent().getExtras();
 if(valores !=null){
    String titulo = valores.getString("Titulo"); 
    String descripcion = valores.getString("Descripcion"); 
    String urlImagen= valores.getString("Titulo"); 

   textViewTitulo.setText(titulo);
   textViewDescripcion.setText(descripcion );

 }
```

para agregar la imagen al  layout puedes usar [**GLIDE**](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) o **[PICASSO](http://square.github.io/picasso/)**, cuya implementación es muy sencilla, o un AsyncTask como el que indico en esta respuesta:
[Descargar Imagen en ImageView](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68161/obtener-una-imagen-de-un-servidor-con-metodo-get)

Comment: Disculpen creo que no me explique bien. Lo único que comparten los items del recyclerview y el activity detalle, es la imagen a través de un shared transition. Todo el contenido de los text view son diferentes. Lo que quise explicar es que los actyvities detalle para cada item comparten el mismo xml, y cambian la información dependiendo el ítem seleccionado. Por lo tanto capaz exista una manera, y seguro la hay, de crear solo un activity detalle que comparta la imagen y cambie los contenidos de sus text view dependiendo el ítem seleccionado. Desde ya muchas gracias por su paciencia.

Comment: En realidad podrías tener una actividad con la imágen y el `RecyclerView` cargarlo dentro de un `Fragment` para esa actividad.