# Asignar un fondo desde una URL a una notificación

Tags: android, android-layout

Tengo una duda de concepto y no de código. Ahora mismo he conseguido con un `remoteviews` cambiar el fondo de mi notificación por el de una imagen ubicada en la carpeta `drawable`.

Mi pregunta es si se puede cambiar la referencia de la imagen por una url de imagen:

`android:src="@drawable/imagen_fondo"` ---> ¿Se podría cambiar por una URL?

Gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido..Javier..., te saludamos y te damos la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, es muy importante leer [ask], saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo solucioné con este tutorial que lo explica todo muy bien. https://futurestud.io/tutorials/picasso-callbacks-remoteviews-and-notifications

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Directamente en un xml no es posible agregar una imagen por url, por medio de codigo tienes diferentes opciones, como por ejemplo:

```
URL url = new URL("www.example.com");
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

O utilizar alguna libreria como picasso.

```
Picasso.with(context)
                .load(ImageURL)
                .resize(width,height).into(imageView);
```

espero te sea de utilidad saludos.

Comment: La primera opción puede provocar NetworkonMainThreadException. :-|

Comment: Cierto, puedes ejecutarlo en un AsyncTask o en un thread para evitar la excepción.

Answer (score 0):

**No se podría cambiar por una url, la referencia `@drawable/` indica un directorio de recursos dentro del proyecto**, ademas este directorio es de "solo lectura", por lo que solo puedes leer los elementos dentro del directorio `/drawable`.

Para descargar imágenes de una manera sencilla y con buen performance teniendo un url, puedes utilizar dos buenas opciones que son las library Glide o Picasso:

[Imageview descargar imagen con Glide o Picasso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/73030/imageview-con-glide-o-picasso)

Ejemplo `Glide`:

Con `Glide`se realiza de forma similar:

```
   Glide.with(context).load(urlImagen).into(imageView);
```

agregando la dependencia dentro de tu archivo build.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    ...
}
```

incluso también puedes usar la clase descrita en esta respuesta que en realidad es un Asynctask el cual tiene como proceso principal la descarga de la imagen mediante una url.

[Obtener una Imagen de un servidor con metodo GET](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/68161/obtener-una-imagen-de-un-servidor-con-metodo-get/68259#68259)

```
 new LoadImage(imageView).execute(urlImagen);
```